What is the significance of the historical scenes shown in the fuzzy projection in "Devs" episode 3?
The third episode of the FX television series Devs shows a fuzzy projection of significant events in human history, such as the creation of cave paintings and the construction of the pyramids. It finishes by showing scenes from Forest's past, but I am not able to identify the remaining events featured in this scene.
It seems like there were shots of some army and some political leader speaking, but I cannot link it to significant historic events. However, I am very curious about the actual meaning of these scenes and their potential relation to the storyline of Devs.

Crucifixion, Roman Legion marching, Looks like Joan of Arc burning at the stake and the Gettysburg address, including the lines "Four score and seven years ago..". After that its the child blowing bubbles. Screaming head then the FY sign at the window.

this link was also a discussion: https://www.reddit.com/r/Devs/comments/fhhsu9/episode_3_backwards_projections_spoilers/

https://youtu.be/YO0-tc3Al9Y?si=pGYuu8WSUKDZ778h

Thank you this helps a lot, especially the YT video. The newly gained knowledge about these scenes makes me appreciate them even more.

Also - https://www.reddit.com/r/Devs/comments/fhaoq7/devs_s01e03_discussion_thread/ - this one as well. Worth noting that theres some debate as to whether it is the army of Genghis Khan or a Roman Legion being depicted. Joan of Arc appears to be saying the Lords Prayer.. With these discussions theres probably a lot of spoilers if you haven't finished watching it.
